# Kubernetes Internal Service IP cannot find pod

Tags: bash, nginx, kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-service

I have the following pod definition to run a basic instance of nginx

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: basic
  labels:
    appName: static-website
spec:
  containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: basic
```

I have made the following service definition

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web-service-local
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
   - targetPort: 80
     port: 80
     nodePort: 30080
  selector:
    appName: static-website
```

❌ When I try to access the nginx page via the service IP it get's stuck

- `kubectl exec --stdin --tty basic -- /bin/bash`
- `curl web-service-local`

I have verified successfully that

- ✅The pod is running correctly as when I run `kubectl get pods` I get

```sh
NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
basic   1/1     Running   0          7m22s
```

- That the service selecter matches the pod label

  - `kubectl describe svc web-service-local |  grep Selector | awk '{print $2}'`
  - `kubectl describe pod basic | grep Labels | awk '{print $2}'`
- ✅I can connect to the pod and nginx is running

  - `kubectl exec --stdin --tty basic -- /bin/bash`
  - `curl localhost` to retrieve the standard nginx homepage.
- ✅ I can connect to the pod and nginx is running and can connect via the IP address

  - `kubectl get pods -l  appName=static-website -o go-template='{{range .items}}{{.status.podIP}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}'`, returns the **POD IP**
  - `kubectl exec --stdin --tty basic -- /bin/bash`
  - `apt update && apt upgrade && apt install dnsutils -y`
  - `curl **POD IP**`(**POD IP**) is from first command
- ✅I can verify that both the service and the pod are in the default namespace

  - `kubectl get pod basic --namespace default` displays the pod
  - `kubectl get svc web-service-local --namespace default`
- ✅I can verify that the DNS has been setup

  - `kubectl exec --stdin --tty basic -- /bin/bash`
  - `apt update && apt upgrade && apt install dnsutils -y`
  - `nslookup web-service-local`, `nslookup web-service-local.default` and `nslookup web-service-local.default.svc.cluster.local` all return the same

```sh
Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Name:   web-service-local.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.106.61.252
```

✅ I have verified that I can access nginx via the Endpoint IP

- `kubectl describe svc web-service-local | grep Endpoints | awk '{print $2}'` **Endpoint IP**
- `kubectl exec --stdin --tty basic -- /bin/bash`
- `curl **Endpoint IP**`

Comment: Your question is off-topic in StackOverflow. You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have NodePort service type implementation, please try with nodeIP:NodePort from the browser or perform the curl as a NodePort service is the most primitive way to get external traffic directly to your service. NodePort, as the name implies, opens a specific port on all the Nodes (the VMs), and any traffic that is sent to this port is forwarded to the service.

```
curl -kvv Nodeip:NodePort
```

Comment: Hello @jdfolino Does this answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration worked. The problem was my local Minikube setup. Once I moved to AKS it was fine